# Bootstrap menu not appearing on ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I'm trying to make a bootstrap menu appearing on the iPad size.

I have used the usual navbar snippet from bootstrap with some modifications. It is all good on phones and laptops but when it comes to iPad the navbar simply get hidden 
here is the link for the top :

`http://sos-optic.com/headss.php`

to view the problem you can use google chrome console --> choose phone view then select iPad.

Comment: http://sos-optic.com/index.php? seems fine to me

Comment: @DanielH try the ipad view : http://imgur.com/a/tVDC3 no navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS rule in your style is hiding it, try to update to the following? I commented out the `display: none;`

After updating your style sheet, do `hard reload` (otherwise your browser will use the cached CSS style sheet)

```
/* Mob Menu */

#mobile-menu {
    /* display: none; */
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @AbderrahimOUAKKI glad to help =D